# Express Javascript file won't including with get method with parameters

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying render the index file with Express Node.js successfully, but if I'm using namespaces with parameter, without parameter render twig file and included own scripts, if I use try with parameter, render ok bu problem with script files path  so script files in head in html cannot including while path not correct

for example, without parameter, in html file style.css look like
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">` path **http://127.0.0.1:3000/style.css**

with parameter, in html file style.css look like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">` path **http://127.0.0.1:3000/mynamespace/style.css** <--- and this not found!

say browser path not found!

Server.js

```
    const port          = 3000;
    const express       = require('express');
    const app           = express();
    const http          = require('http');
    const socketIO      = require('socket.io');
    const server        = http.Server(app);

    server.listen(this.port, () => {
        console.log(`Server running on: http://127.0.0.1:${port}`);
    });

    const io = socketIO(server);


    app.set('view engine', 'twig');
    app.set('views', "views");

    app.use(express.static('public'));
    app.use(express.static('scripts'));
    app.use(express.static("styles"));

    /// Routing

    /**
     * This work fine
     * Render client.twig
     * Including Scripts in head
     */

    app.get('/mynamespace', function (req, res, next) {
        res.render("client");
    });

    /**
     * This work with error
     * Render client.twig
     * don't Including Scripts in head
     * 
     */
    app.get('/mynamespace/:id', function (req, res, next) {
        res.render("client");
    });


    io.of("/mynamespace").on('connection',(socket)=>{

        socket.on('online_users', (data) => {
            console.log(`Online Users ${data}`);
        });
    });
```

client.js

```
let url = `http://127.0.0.1:3000/mynamespace`;
console.log("Url", url);
this.socket =  io(url);

this.socket.on("connect", ()=>{
        try{
            this.socket.emit('welcome', {
                message:"Welcome guest"
            });
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e.message);
        }
});
```

client.twig

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" const="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>RestoCommend</title>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"
</head>

<body>
<h3>Client</h3>

<script src="helper.js"></script>
<script src="client.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

From your code it looks like the `style.css` file is in the same directory as `client.twig` which is the `views` directory. But you have told express that the static directories are `public`, `scripts` and `styles`. There is no instruction for express to know where to serve the css from. Try moving the style.css file into styles directory.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank for answers, my hierarchy of files 

My hierarchy of files 

Root > Public.          > 'socket.io.js, Helper.js '
Root > scripts          > 'main.js, support.js, index.js'
Root > styles           > 'main.css, support.css, index.css'
Root > serv              > 'server.js'
Root > views            > 'main.twig, support.twig, index.twig'

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to [serve your static files under a relative path](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html). Try the following:

```
app.use('/mynamespace', express.static('public'))
app.use('/mynamespace', express.static('scripts'))
app.use('/mynamespace', express.static('styles'))
```

And also

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mynamespace/style.css" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your idea, ich have checked your link and solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

My hierarchy of files

[image]

I Solved my problem, but not good idea

Server.js

```
app.get('/mynamespace1', function (req, res, next) {
     app.use(express.static('public'));
     app.use(express.static('scripts'));
     app.use(express.static("styles"));
     res.render("client1");
});
```

one parameter based namespace!

```
app.get('/mynamespace2/:clientId', function (req, res, next) {
     app.use(express.static(path.join( __dirname + "/../", 'public')))
     app.use(express.static(path.join( __dirname + "/../", 'scripts')))
     app.use(express.static(path.join( __dirname + "/../", 'styles')))
     res.render("client2");
});
```

more as one parameter based namespace!

```
app.get('/mynamespace3/:roomName/:clientId', function (req, res, next) {
     app.use(express.static(path.join( __dirname + "/../", 'public')))
     app.use(express.static(path.join( __dirname + "/../", 'scripts')))
     app.use(express.static(path.join( __dirname + "/../", 'styles')))
     res.render("client3");
});
```

client1.twig

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="helper.js"></script>
<script src="client.js"></script>
```

Everything normal

client2.twig

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css">
<script src="../helper.js"></script>
<script src="../client.js"></script>
```

with one prameter, script paths defined to parent

client3.twig

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../style.css">
<script src="../../helper.js"></script>
<script src="../../client.js"></script>
```

with more prameters, parent folder defined, until number of parameter

My Problem solved, but I don't like it so